# Why does my JTextField resize when I change the size of my JTextArea?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I'm having a lot of trouble with this GUI. I'm going to have an applet that has panel1 on the left side, and panel2 on the right side. Here are my two problems: 1) The JTextArea needs to take up the whole right side of the applet, but I can't make it do that. 2) Whenever I make the JTextArea longer, the JTextField gets longer as well, even though it's in a whole different panel. What's going on? The applet and everything is created in another class - it compiles and runs fine. I just can't get this part to work.

```
private JButton button1;

  private JLabel label1;
private JTextField field1;
private JPanel panel1;
private JPanel panel2;
private JPanel panel3;
private JTextArea area1;
int i = 0;
int j = 0;
private JScrollPane pane;


public Class()
{


this.petList = petList;
this.sPanel = sPanel;

panel1 = new JPanel();
panel1.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
button1 = new JButton("Test");
panel1.add(button1,BorderLayout.SOUTH);
field1 = new JTextField();
panel1.add(field1, BorderLayout.EAST);
label1 = new JLabel("Test");
panel1.add(label1, BorderLayout.WEST);

panel2 = new JPanel();
area1 = new JTextArea(10, 20);
panel2.add(area1);

panel3 = new JPanel();
panel3.setLayout(new BorderLayout(5,5));
panel3.add(panel1, BorderLayout.WEST);
panel3.add(panel2, BorderLayout.EAST);

this.add(panel3);
```

Comment: This is the nature of `BorderLayout`

Comment: So what would be a better choice? I also tried boxlayout, which didn't work either. I know someone that got this to work exactly like it's supposed to using only borderlayout.

Comment: It would be better to use GridBagLayout

Comment: i would suggest you to use `Netbeans GUI Builder`. Its great and easy to use.

Comment: @SuKu While I use Netbeans form editor in my day to day development, I would always encourage developers to know how to hand code a UI first. It's especially important that they understand what the layout managers are doing. It allows them to make better choices when choosing a layout manager as well as diagnose problems when it blows up in there faces - IMHO

Comment: 1) Use a consistent and logical indent for code blocks. The indentation of the code is intended to help people understand the program flow. 2) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: @user2067506: Please don't vandalize you question.

Answer (score 5):

Your idea is a good one, compound layouts make it easier to layout multiple components, but your choice of layout managers was a little off.

The nature of `BorderLayout` is to use all the available space to layout it's components.

Try using something like `GridBagLayout` instead

[image]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class BadLayout12 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new BadLayout12();
    }

    public BadLayout12() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        private JButton button1;
        private JLabel label1;
        private JTextField field1;
        private JPanel panel1;
        private JPanel panel2;
        private JPanel panel3;
        private JTextArea area1;
        int i = 0;
        int j = 0;
        private JScrollPane pane;

        public TestPane() {

//            this.petList = petList;
//            this.sPanel = sPanel;

            button1 = new JButton("Test");
            field1 = new JTextField(10);
            label1 = new JLabel("Test");

            panel1 = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
            GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbc.gridx = 0;
            gbc.gridy = 0;
            panel1.add(label1, gbc);
            gbc.gridx++;
            panel1.add(field1, gbc);
            gbc.gridx = 0;
            gbc.gridy++;
            gbc.gridwidth = 2;
            panel1.add(button1, gbc);

            panel2 = new JPanel();
            area1 = new JTextArea(10, 20);
            panel2.add(new JScrollPane(area1));

            panel3 = new JPanel();
            panel3.setLayout(new BorderLayout(5, 5));
            panel3.add(panel1, BorderLayout.WEST);
            panel3.add(panel2, BorderLayout.EAST);

            this.add(panel3);
        }
    }
}
```

Take a look at;

- [A Visual Guide to Layout Managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html)
- http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/using.html

For more details